# random values from specific function python

Tags: python, function, random

let's say I want to pull out random values from a linear distribution function, I'm not sure how I would do that..
say I have a function y = 3x then I want to be able to pull out a random value from that line.
this is what I've tried:

```
 x,y = [],[]
 for i in range(10):
    a = random.uniform(0,3)
    x.append(a)
    b = 3*a
    y.append(b)
```

This gives me y values that are taken from this linear function (distribution per say). Now if this is correct, how would I do the same for a distribution that looks like a horizontal line?

that is what if I had a horizontal line function y = 3, how can I get random values pulled out from there?

Comment: You'll need a better understanding of what a distribution is to solve your problem, because what you have is not a distribution.

Comment: Cumulative distribution functions are indeed defined in this way. I'm not sure if you have a clear understanding of my question dear comrade.

Comment: A cumulative distribution function is required to have values in the range `[0, 1]`. `y = 3x` doesn't fit that criterion.

Comment: cumulative distribution is defined as F(x) = x for x in [0,1]. Adding a scaling factor of 3 doesn't do any harm to the pseudo-random nature of the distribution function. would only change the limits. No big deal. http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3662.htm

Comment: Do acknowledge that you have a point :)

Comment: You really need to specify the bounds. Also, your "horizontal line function", scaled and bounded properly, describes a distribution that always produces 0, so the function to generate random values from that distribution would be `def f(): return 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your function, using a lambda or explicit definition,  and then call it to get the y-value:

```
def func(x):
    return 3

points = []
for i in range(10):
    x = random.uniform(0, 3)
    points.append((x, func(x))
```

A linear function with a slope of 0 in this case is fairly trivial.

EDIT: I think I understand that question a little more clearly now. You are looking to randomly generate a point that lies under the curve? That is quite tricky to directly calculate for an arbitrary function, and you probably will want a bound to your function (i.e a < x < b). Supposing we have a bound, one simple method would be to generate a random number in a box containing the curve, and simply discard it if it isn't under the curve. This will be perfectly random.

```
def linearfunc(x):
    return 3 * x

def getRandom(func, maxi, a, b):
    while True:
        x = random.uniform(a, b)
        y = random.uniform(0, maxi)
        if y < func(x):
            return (x, y)

points = [getRandom(linearFunc, 9, 0, 3) for i in range(10)]
```

This method requires knowing an upper bound (maxi) to the function on the specified interval, and the tighter the upper bound, the less sampling misses will occur.

Comment: but aren't the values in the array points same as x? just a random uniform bunch of values between 0 and 3. how can I ensure it's from the function?

Comment: the output i want is just an array with single element values that are solution to the function mentioned.

Comment: similar to how numpy.random.normal(mu,sigma,size) gives single element values array of the specified size that are acquired from the normal distribution specified, I'm looking to get values analogous to this.

Comment: I responded, but I'm not 100% sure I'm completely understanding what you're looking for. Let me know if this isn't it

Comment: So yes, I do have bounds 0 to 3 specified. I think your updated solution is on it's way. I've rephrased the question here to better explain it. I don't want values from under the curve, I want random values FROM the curve, or from the LINE in this case. Thank you very much for your help regardless!! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209244/sloped-uniform-distribution-python